# How does one add all values that occur before a specific date?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, iwork-numbers, worksheet-function

I know I need the `SUMIF` function, but I can't figure out the condition for the life of me. Given the following table, how would I get $150?

```
Value |   Date
------+---------
 $100 | 1/1/2013
  $50 | 1/2/2013
  $25 | 1/3/2013
```

I would think it's something like `SUMIF(B2:B4, "<=?", A2:A4)`, but I don't know what goes where the question mark is. Even hard-coding a date wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m curious what you did try if `=SUMIF(B2:B4, "<=1/2/2013", A2:A4)` wasn’t one of them. 
If you want the cut-off date to be determined by the spreadsheet, e.g., a date value in cell `Z1`, use `=SUMIF(B2:B4, "<="&Z1, A2:A4)`, where `&` is the concatenate operator.

Comment: The first example worked. For some reason, I was trying to use the `DATEVALUE` function in there. Not sure why. Thanks.